# Logstash: Replacing timestamp from message not working

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

Replacing timestamp of the event with the timestamp of the message is not working for me. Here are the details.

Sample log:

```
20170119 144002.184140 0005B9427CA0_CU_1 user.notice ProcMon:: 10.220.0.13 is valid IP Address
```

Pattern:

```
CSSYSLOGTIMESTAMP  %{YEAR}%{MONTHNUM}%{MONTHDAY}[T ]%{HOUR}%{MINUTE}%{SECOND}.%{NONNEGINT:MSEC}
```

Filter:

```
filter {
  grok {
    patterns_dir => ["/root/logstash-5.5.0/patterns"]
    match => { "message" => "^%{CSSYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{DATA:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_level} %{DATA:app_name}: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
  }

  date {
    match => ["syslog_timestamp" , "yyyyMMdd HHmmss.SSS"]
    target => "@timestamp"
    add_field => { "debug" => "timestampMatched"}
  }
}
```

Logstash Debug output:

```
[2017-07-18T10:25:01,152][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] filter received {"event"=>{"@timestamp"=>2017-07-18T04:54:55.170Z, "offset"=>747452, "@version"=>"1", "input_type"=>"log", "beat"=>{"hostname"=>"node1", "name"=>"node1", "version"=>"5.5.0"}, "host"=>"node1", "source"=>"/root/samplelogs/Debug.log", "message"=>"20170119 144002.184140 0005B9427CA0_CU_1 user.notice ProcMon:: 10.220.0.13 is valid IP Address", "type"=>"log", "tags"=>["beats_input_codec_plain_applied"]}}
[2017-07-18T10:25:01,154][DEBUG][logstash.filters.grok    ] Running grok filter {:event=>2017-07-18T04:54:55.170Z node1 20170119 144002.184140 0005B9427CA0_CU_1 user.notice ProcMon:: 10.220.0.13 is valid IP Address}
[2017-07-18T10:25:01,159][DEBUG][logstash.filters.grok    ] Event now:  {:event=>2017-07-18T04:54:55.170Z node1 20170119 144002.184140 0005B9427CA0_CU_1 user.notice ProcMon:: 10.220.0.13 is valid IP Address}
[2017-07-18T10:25:01,165][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] output received {"event"=>{"MSEC"=>"184140", "offset"=>747452, "input_type"=>"log", "source"=>"/root/samplelogs/Debug.log", "message"=>"20170119 144002.184140 0005B9427CA0_CU_1 user.notice ProcMon:: 10.220.0.13 is valid IP Address", "type"=>"log", "syslog_message"=>"10.220.0.13 is valid IP Address", "tags"=>["beats_input_codec_plain_applied", "_dateparsefailure"], "app_name"=>"ProcMon:", "@timestamp"=>2017-07-18T04:54:55.170Z, "syslog_hostname"=>"0005B9427CA0_CU_1", "syslog_timestamp"=>"20170119 144002.184140", "@version"=>"1", "beat"=>{"hostname"=>"node1", "name"=>"node1", "version"=>"5.5.0"}, "host"=>"node1", "syslog_level"=>"user.notice"}}
```

I can see all the fields are extracted correctly. The message timestamp is created in field syslog_timestamp. However the @timestamp is not being replaced with the message timestamp. 
What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. I was only using upto 3 decimals (SSS) because of this text mentioned in the reference doc.

```
"S: fraction of a second Maximum precision is milliseconds (SSS). Beyond that, zeroes are appended."
```

But it turns out you still need to use 6 S's while defining the filter.

Comment: The date.match doesn't work like grok.match. The date.match requires a whole string to exactly fit the pattern. Extra characters are not tolerated.